# How to pass data to one module to another module in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my project I have two `ng-app's` one is for `login page` and another for `home page`.

Once login is successful for the user, in `ajax success callback` I got the some response related to that user and in that callback I am used the `window.location="home.html"`.

As of now I used session storage feature to pass the data to home page.

Comment: Please share some codes!

Comment: What kind of data would you need to have your login page pass to your home page? Shouldn't you have your back-end pass those, instead of the front-end?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is by creating a service. The service can be injected into your controllers and other services as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service and use getter and setters.When you get a response in your first module set the object using setter and get the data using getter in another module.

The best way to communicate between two controllers or say two modules is using services.

Answer (score 0):

According To angularjs examples only one module stands for one project though outof the box you can you can use more than one

but To Achieve this .This Is how i Normally model myproject

```
 **MyProjectModule**  (only **one** module)

    ---> loginController.js (initial page)
   (If LOGIN IS Authorised Then Redirect To Desktop->desktopController.js)

    ---> desktopController.js

    ---> customerController.js

    ---> salesController.js
```